# How to add dummy data to end of dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have 700 column data frame.

I want to add `a` to every column in the last row how do I do this?

```
col. col2
1.    2
3.    2
a.    a
```

Comment: As a new row?  Or overwrite the existing last row?

Comment: @piRSquared new row

Comment: @AntonvBR could you please give me an example

Comment: This may just be a meaningless example you've provided, but be aware that if you add a row of strings to a DataFrame of integers, all the dtypes are now `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loc (and passing the length of dataframe) works in most cases:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = 'a'
```

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2],
    'col2': [3, 4]
})

df.loc[len(df)] = 'a'

print(df)

#  col1 col2
#0    1    3
#1    2    4
#2    a    a
```

**Small warning**: This assumes you have an index that starts with 0. (And as the index start with 0, the len(df) is the next number in line.)

**Possible workaround if index is not numbered correctly**: use `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @RustyShackleford And as the index start with 0, the len(df) is the next number in line.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Place with `loc`

Note that I specify the index value of `'new_idx'`.  I'm not making any assumptions about your index.  Even if you use `len(df)`, that may have already existed as an index value.  I can't know that.  So it is on you to use an index value that is new.  If it isn't new, then this will overwrite the existing row.

```
df.loc['new_idx'] = ['a' for _ in range(df.shape[1])]
```

---

#### In Line with `append`

This is less stringent.  If the index value `'new_idx'` already exists in `df.index`, this will make another row with a duplicate index value.

```
df.append(pd.Series('a', df.columns, name='new_idx'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loc method like the following :

```
#df being the original dataframe
df.loc[len(df)] = [ 'a' for _ in range(df.shape[1])]
```